# Accidentally Deleted and wipe OS X partition while Extending the boot-camp partition

Tags: macos, boot, restore

My Macbook pro is the late 2017 version with touch bar and the OSX is Mojave.

I used a windows tools NIUBI to extend my bootcamp partion. The tool showed unallocated space, so I wipe the unallocated space and extended the boot-camp partition successfully. When I try to boot back to my OSX, I realised the unallocated space was actually the OSX main partition. The data in OSX is certainly not recoverable but I want to retain the boot-camp installation without re-install windows.

I use the NIUBI inside the windows environment to create a new partion for OSX. Then I use Command-R trying the install the OSX, the partition was grey out, and I am not able to select the new partition created by NIUBI which is a windows tool.

The disk utility also don't allow me to select the partition and I cannot format the partition.

Any suggestions or comments:

In windows environment, I am able to initialize the un-allocated partition to 0 and 1s like a new drive. Does this step help the OSX recovery tool or disk utility tool to recognize the partition so that I can reformat the partition to disk journalized for installation of Majave .

Any other suggestions to help me detect the partition or re-install the OSX WITHOUT destroying the boot-camp data and also bootable for both OS are highly apprecaiated.

Answer (score 0):

Golden rule - don't ever attempt to work on the partitioning from inside Windows. It doesn't realise it's being fooled into thinking it's in charge.

[Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/) *might* be able to fix it, or at least let you clone the Bootcamp volume to another drive then restore after you reformatted the drive, but don't get your hopes up.